# Paper.js equivalent for Raphael's setViewBox (Zooming in/out on Window Resize)

Tags: canvas, svg, resize, raphael, paperjs

I am trying to paint the same elements with paperjs on a bunch of different devices in realtime (paths are exchanged via nodejs).

Problem: A smartphone in it's portrait mode has a very limited screen width.

I've found this fiddle for Raphael:

http://jsfiddle.net/vnTQT/

The resizing is achieved in the example with

```
paper.setViewBox(0,0,w,h,true);
paper.setSize('100%', '100%');
```

This behaviour is exactly what I need.
The problem: I am using paper.js currently and don't want to rewrite my component completely.

Is there any way to do the same with paper.js?

Comment: You might try describing what you want to happen. I don't know about most paperjs users, but I don't know Raphael at all so I don't understand what `setViewBox` does implicitly.

Comment: I wanted to scale my canvas elements to the given zoom or display resolution.  See the fiddle as an example. A Smartphone in landscape mode has a very limited display width, so all the drawn elements (paths and circles) should scale relatively to that width.

Comment: I ran the fiddle but didn't see anything. I'm not sure why. What you're saying is that no matter what size the canvas is you want the display elements to be proportional? I understand this for screen resolution, but doesn't zoom imply that you're scaling up/down the elements for zoom in/out?

Comment: Hm, strange ,the Fiddle works just fine here on my PC.

For me "resizing elements proportionally (according to the canvas size)" is some kind of zoom. Maybe this word is confusing if you relate my question to  the actual "zoom" functionality in Paperjs. 

"How can I resize my Elements proportionally to the given display size?" 

To reduce the complexity of the question, my base canvas has a width and height of 1000x1000. It must be scaled up or down.

Comment: All I see is an orange canvas square when I run the fiddle - no vectors, etc. I'll take a stab at the answer though I'm not sure you'll find it satisfying.

Comment: If the answer does answer your question it would be great if you accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do what you want with paperjs. I have implemented a number of projects that resize proportionally when the canvas is resized but I do so by 1) specifying the size and position of each element as a fraction of the screen size and 2) redrawing the canvas on the resize event.

If I want a circle to be placed in the center of the canvas with a diameter of 10% of the smallest dimension of the canvas:

```
var pos = paper.view.bounds.center;
var size = 0.1 * Math.min(
                     paper.view.size.width,
                     paper.view.size.height
                 );

var circle = new paper.Path.Circle({
    center: pos,
    radius: size/2,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 1
});
```

You may want to change the strokeWidth as well. And you'll have to ersase/redraw it each time the canvas is resized.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, so I really have to erase / redraw everything onresize? Would such a operation cost a lot of performance? Do you have experiences with that on mobile?

Comment: It doesn't cause a performance problem - Raphael actually does the same thing behind the scenes because there is no native canvas function. I have used this technique for relatively complex designs (see https://www.whale.ee/designs/palettenrolli) without notable issues. The design (palettenrolli) is redrawn completely on a resize event or a change in the number of columns, but not on rotating the colors.

Comment: Mobile - it runs beautifully on my Nexus 6 but I haven't tested on other phones. My partner on whale.ee runs it on iPhones and finds that works well too, but I don't feedback outside of that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `paper.view.scale` and a redraw in the resize event.

See http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#scale-scale